# finding the integrating factor of $y \ dx+(x+3x^{3}y^{4}) \ dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Let
$$M=y \; \mbox{and} \; N=x+3x^3y^4$$

We know that our integrating factor will be determined by

$$\mu = e^{\int g(x) \ dx}$$

$g(x)$ will be obtained by assuming that there is a general solution for the differential equation we are trying to solve. $g(x)$ is given by

$$\frac{\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}- \frac{\partial N}{\partial N}}{N}$$

$\Rightarrow \frac{1-(1+9x^2y^4)}{x+3x^2y^4}$

$\Rightarrow - \frac{9xy^4}{1+3x^2y^4}=g(x)$

so far so good, this means our integrating factor will be given by

$\mu = e^{\int \frac{-9xy^4}{1+3x^2y^4}dx}$

$\Rightarrow e^{-\frac{3}{2}ln(1+3x^2y^4)}$

$\Rightarrow \mu = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+3x^2y^4)^3}}$

the problem is that my textbook indicates that the integrating factor is $\frac{1}{(xy)^3}$ I can't seem to understand the mistake I'm making any help would be much appreciated

Comment: That formula is for when $g$ is a function of $x$ alone,  in your case it is a function of both $x$ and $y$, so it cannot be used

Comment: it's Bernoulli's DE in $x'$  you can easily solve it.

Comment: @Alan how am I able to determine when a differential equation is dependent of two values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y \ dx+(x+3x^{3}y^{4}) \ dy = 0$$
$$ydx+xdy+3x^{3}y^{4}\ dy = 0$$
$$d(xy)+3x^{3}y^{4}\ dy = 0$$
The integrating factor is now obvious:
$$\mu (x,y)= \dfrac  1 {(xy)^3}$$
$$\dfrac {d(xy)}{x^3y^3}+3ydy=0$$
Integrate. The integrating factor given is correct. It depends on both $x$ and $y$ not only on $x$.
You can find the correct formula for this kind of integrating factor here at section 3 : [Formula integrating factor](https://www.math24.net/using-integrating-factor)